# Getting Exact precision of decimal places from a double in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, regex, .net-3.5

Due to a requirement I need very exact precision of a double value to a 4 decimal places as follows:

```
double myDoubleValue = 50234.9489898997952932;
```

From the above, I need the output as `50234.9489`. **I DON'T want Rounding the number in this requirement.**

I came across with  "Math.Truncate(a * 100) / 100;". But really i'm not interested with this approach.

I'm looking for better approach very simple way something like using `String.Format` or with `Regular Expressions` etc.

Comment: The `double` type is in imprecise numeric type. If you need _precise_ numerics, then you need to use `decimal`.

Comment: Sorry for delay, Regex modified to handle double without decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without regexes:

**This works very much fine for any `double` combinations**

```
using System.Globalization;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double d = 50234.9489898997952932;
        char probablyDot = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0];
        string[] number = d.ToString().Split(probablyDot);


        //Console.WriteLine(number[0] + probablyDot + number[1].Remove(4));

        Console.WriteLine(number[0] + probablyDot + (number.Length >1 ? (number[1].Length>4? number[1].Substring(0,4):number[1]): "0000"));
        //Output: 50234.9489

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a very straight forward and simple code. Is there a simple way with 1 or 2 lines of code

Comment: My solution has two lines: `string[] numbers = d.ToString.Split('.');` and `string output = numbers[0] + '.' + numbers[1].Remove(4);` The _great_ disadvantage of my method is it crashes if your double doesn't have at least four decimal places.

Comment: THis is very bad. Since the input double value may have 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or many decimals. This shouldn't be fixed as constant. Please do needful in getting right answer for the same.

Comment: I changed my answer (please note you should have written this in your question, I really thought the input would always have more than four decimal places), now I can't fit in your requirement of "1 or 2 lines of code", but all cases are covered.

Comment: I edited your answer with the change as  `Console.WriteLine(number[0] + probablyDot + (number.Length >1 ? (number[1].Length>4? number[1].Substring(0,4):number[1]): "0000"));`

This works for any type of combinations. I don't have EDIT privilege this may cause for you to not see the my edited change. But the change is showing at my side.

Comment: Ooops, you edited it at the same time I did... The difference in our edits is you used a ternary, so the code can fit in two lines (+ 1 for that). Thank you for approving.

Comment: Ooops (2): I added the last comment while you were adding yours, this asynchronous operations are hell ;)
Anyway, I approved your edits in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
double d = 50234.94895345345345;
var Expected_result =  Double.Parse((Regex.Match(d.ToString(), "[+-]?\\d*.\\d{0,4}")).Value);
```

Comment: This doesn't play nice if you're double has no decimal places. Try changing the first line to `double d = 1` and see what you get for `p`.

Comment: @sanguine: Then How to get the result if the double has no decimal places??

Comment: @Mark: Then how to rewrite this regular expression for getting result if double has no decimal places???

Comment: @sukumar see the answer I just posted.

Comment: @Sukumar, Regex modified to handle double without decimals.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to do this yourself. One of the possible solutions would be to use an extension method

```
public static class DoubleEx
{
    public static double TruncateFraction(this double value, int fractionRound)
    {
        double factor = Math.Pow(10, fractionRound);
        return Math.Truncate(value * factor) / factor;
    }
}
```

And this is how to use it

```
double foo = 50234.9489898997952932;
double bar = foo.TruncateFraction(4);

Console.WriteLine(foo); //50234.9489898997952932
Console.WriteLine(bar); //50234.9489
```

Comment: I just tested this method and it seems to return 1.5553 if I do `((double)1.5554).TruncateFraction(4)`. I would expect it to return 1.5554.

Comment: Your approach is might complex. But i'm expecting very straight forward with a single line of code. Anyhow, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of answers here that work with the input given in the question, but on testing them with a range of values, they all have limitations (see comments).

The only way I can see to achieve this with any decimal input is the following. It might not be a one liner, but it seems robust to me.

```
private static string TrimDecimalPlaces(double value, int numberOfDecimalPlaces)
{
    string valueString = value.ToString();

    if (!valueString.Contains(".")) return valueString;

    int indexOfDot = valueString.IndexOf(".");

    if ((indexOfDot + numberOfDecimalPlaces + 1) < valueString.Length)
    {
        return valueString.Remove(indexOfDot + numberOfDecimalPlaces + 1);
    }
    return valueString;
}
```

I've tested this with the following test data and the results are as expected:

- 1
- 1.1
- 1.11
- 1.111
- 1.1111
- 1.11111
- 1.111111
- -1
- -1.1
- -1.11
- -1.111
- -1.1111
- -1.11111
- -1.111111

Comment: Please see the answer `Without regexes:` in the above very simplest way and i acheived the same.